# Как в UTF-16 определить младший и старший байт

Tags: utf-8, unicode

Подавляющее большинство процессоров и каналов связи используют побайтную адресацию. Как для кода UTF-16 определить младший или старший байт. В UTF-8 это очень просто.

Comment: cамый простой способ - по BOM

Comment: Я имел в виду не порядок байт в символе а его границу в побайтовом массиве.

Comment: Очевидно, она будет кратна 2-м байтам от начала массива + учет order (который должен быть известен заранее). В чем вообще задача? У вас некий неизвестный кусок памяти, и в нем надо найти UTF-16 строку?

Comment: А если начало неизвестно? В ASCII и UTF-8 в этом проблем нет.

Comment: Если начало неизвестно - значит не повезло.

Answer (score 1):

Никак. Однозначно определить гранцу символа в UTF-16 невозможно. А для установления порядка байт нужен BOM. Например три следующих подряд сивола D700,D700,D700, при сдвиге на один байт дадут XXD7,00D7,00D7, что тоже тоже символы из первого диаппазона. Можно конечно прибегнуть к анализу данных, но результат будет неоднознаный.

Answer (score 0):

Можно использовать ту же эвристику, что применяется для определения порядка байт в отсутствии BOM: считать пробелы (`0x0020`). Пробел является самым часто встречаемым символом в текстах на большинстве языков (подозреваю, что в языках с иероглифическим письмом это не так).

Итак, есть два параметра:

- Читаем с четного или нечетного байта
- Прямой или обратный порядок байтов

Нужно перебрать четыре варианта. С большой вероятностью верен тот, где много вхождений `0x0020`.